# for loop to a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to change this into a while loop.

```
number = int(input("enter number : "))
exponent = int(input("enter exponent : "))
result = number

for i in range(1, exponent):
    result = number * result
print(number, " to the power of ", exponent, " is ", result)
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a `while` loop?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to change it to a while loop?

Comment: in python you have exponentiation operator `**`

Comment: There are many good Python tutorials out there that can teach you how to write a `while` loop.

Comment: The task required a while loop instead of the operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 possibilities :

```
number = int(input("enter number : "))
exponent = int(input("enter exponent : "))

# 1st possibility
result = number
for i in range(1, exponent):
    result = number * result
print(number, " to the power of ", exponent, " is ", result)


# 2nd possibility
result = number
i = 1
while i < exponent:
    result = number * result
    i += 1

print(number, " to the power of ", exponent, " is ", result)

# 3rd possibility
print(number, " to the power of ", exponent, " is ", number**exponent)

# 4th possibility
print(number, " to the power of ", exponent, " is ", pow(number, exponent))
```

You should probably pick #3 or #4 ;).

Comment: 4. `pow` builtin function.

Comment: @tobias_k: Is there any advantage of using `pow`? The doc mentions that it's equivalent to `**`.

Comment: "With two arguments, equivalent to `x**y`.  _With three arguments, equivalent to `(x**y) % z`, but may be more efficient (e.g. for longs)_." But, yeah, it's mostly equivalent, but so are the other two variants.

Comment: @tobias_k Good to know, thanks.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I definitely understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input("enter number : "))
exponent = int(input("enter exponent : "))
result = number
i = 1
while i < exponent:
    result = number * result
    i += 1
print(number, " to the power of ", exponent, " is ", result)
```

Is that what you were looking for?